# "pool.execute" (Thread pool executer) usage in Java 7

Tags: java, multithreading

Some piece of code from my project is as follows:

```
 pool.execute(() -> 
            {   
                boolean flag = true;
                while (flag)
                {
                    if (ev3ColorSensor.getColorID() == Color.BLACK)
                    {
                        LuuMa.setSwitching(true);
                        int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(5) + 1;

                        if (randomInt == 1)
                        {
                            try {
                                pause();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        else if (randomInt == 2)
                        {
                            fastOff();
                        }
                        else if (randomInt == 3)
                        {
                            intimidate();
                        }
                        else if (randomInt == 4)
                        {
                            try {
                                peekFastOff();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        else if (randomInt == 5)
                        {
                            psych();
                        }
                        else if (randomInt == 6)
                        {
                            try {
                                delay();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    LuuMa.setSwitching(false);
                }
            });
```

I'm working on a lejos ev3 project. And Lejos ev3 doesn't support Java 8. For this reason, I must use Java 7 to compile my project on the ev3 brick.

I need to use `pool.execute` for parallel processing. But Java 7 doesn't support it. How can I solve the problem, or which alternative can I use in Java 7?

Thanks,

Comment: You are using Java8 lambda syntax. First try to change it back to anonymous classes.

Comment: "But Java 7 doesn't support it." <-- of course it does. Where did you see that Java 7 didn't support parallel execution?

Comment: That's what I'm asking @Gabor. How can I manage it? :)

Comment: Java 7 of course support but doesn't support pool.execute, or am I wrong?

Comment: @yusuf: `pool.execute` is just calling the `execute` method on a variable called `pool`. Without knowing the type of `pool`, how can we possibly say whether or not it's supported on Java 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use an anonymous inner class instead - Java 7 doesn't support lambda expressions, but it certainly supports parallel execution.

```
pool.execute(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
        // Code here
    }
});
```

Obviously change `Callable` and `run` to whatever the suitable interface and method names are in this case - we don't know the type of `pool` in your code. If the type of `pool` isn't supported in Java 7, you could use something like `ExecutorService`.